# How to represent an initial unpopulated value?

Tags: usability, website-design, interaction-design, user-behavior, user-expectation

What is considered a feasible representation of a value that has yet to be loaded? Would something such as the -- placeholder be sufficient or is there something else that is better suited / widely know for the user?

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### If the value will populate, set your users expectations where they will see the value appear. Let them know the system is working to return the value...

#### Give the user the feeling of control (system status)

From first glance, using the -- makes the value look Null, or irrelevant.
If the application will certainly deliver a value, wether that's 0% up to 100%, it's crucial they be shown the **system status**.

Jakob Nielsen emphasizes **[Visibility of System Status](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/)**:

> The system should always keep users informed about what is going on, through appropriate feedback within reasonable time.

#### How to show status

Here you have some choices. You could:

- use a loading... (where the ellipsis [can animate several ways](https://github.com/adorableio/react-native-animated-ellipsis))
- a spinner

[image]

**NOTE:**
I didn't mention a percentage loading bar, since your final value is a percentage itself.

Answer (score -1):

> What is considered a feasible representation of a value that has yet
>   to be loaded?

This is commonly referred to as a "loader" image, most commonly done with .gif files.

[image: A LOADER]

If you use google image search and/or any of the image/design sites you'll find more examples than you can imagine, and probably something ideal for what you're doing.

Type in the following to an image search:

loader gif